Missing Contact Form/Form Default Plugin in Wordpress
I'm currently using wordpress to develop website and as much as possible doesnot want to use any plugins.
When I want to add contact form I see the link below which looks like a default plugin, but when I search in my available blocks is it not available.
https://wordpress.com/support/wordpress-editor/blocks/form-block/
I'm using Wordpress 6.6.1

That article refers to features on wordpress.com, which uses a modified version of WordPress. That block is not available in a default install of WordPress.
What's your reasoning for avoiding plugins? They're the intended method for adding functionality.

I'm new to Wordpress and I am reading a lots of articles that there are vulnerabilities on plugins so I avoid it as much as possible. And thank you for poiting that the Form is not available in default wordpress installation.

Every piece of software that's ever existed has vulnerabilities. WP core, plugins, everything. The important thing is that they're fixed as soon as they're discovered. You should be fine if you stick to actively developed, popular plugins.

Thank you Chris Cox!
